# Using SSL Certificates in Python2.7.*

Tags: python, ssl

I'm on a corporate network I need to use certificates for to get access to certain pages. I've tried looking around online for a module that'll retrieve an HTTPS webpage and also allow me to specify which certificate I want to use. I have this code:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://k9ballistics.com/",'lxml')
thing = page.content
thing = thing.split('\n')
for m in thing:
    if '<tr>' in m:
        print m
```

This works on retrieving a normal HTTPS page, but when I try to access our page it throws this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

I was hoping to find a way to do it with a module that already comes with Python as opposed to relying on a pip installed package for portability's sake.

I'm on Windows, but I have my certificates from my linux workstation in a folder I'd like to point to, and also have Ubuntu Bash on Windows.

Comment: the URL listed is an example of a normal HTTPS site that I can retrieve source code from. The internal domain is not listed in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass verify the path to a `CA_BUNDLE` file or directory with certificates of trusted `CAs`:

```
requests.get('https://eg.com', verify='/path/to/certfile.pem')
```

or persistent:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = '/path/to/certfile.pem'
```

Also you can ignore verifying the SSL certificate by `verify=False`.

Have a look at [SSL Cert Verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) to see more details.

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error, but in this case I think these may just not be the certificates I need. You answered my question though so thank you for that!